# ValueError: 'X' is not in list, why cannot I not find and replace using a string

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

So I have a list with numbers in strings from 01 - 64, created like so:

```
 gBoard = [
    ['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08'],
    ['09','10','11','12','13','14','15','16'],
    ['17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24'],
    ['25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32'],
    ['33','34','35','36','37','38','39','40'],
    ['41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48'],
    ['49','50','51','52','53','54','55','56'],
    ['57','58','59','60','61','62','63','64']]
```

For my game, I need to add tokens to these numbers, so if a player chooses that number, it would look like so:

```
gBoard = [
['01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08'],
['09','10','11 ##','12','13','14','15','16'],
['17','18','19','20','21','22','23','24'],
['25','26','27','28','29','30','31','32'],
['33','34','35','36','37 @@','38','39','40'],
['41','42','43','44','45','46','47','48'],
['49','50','51','52','53','54','55','56 ##'],
['57','58','59','60','61','62','63','64 ##']]
```

This then takes the players input, finds the first iteration of that number and saves its index to indexOne, in theory:

```
print(playerone, "It is your turn to play, type a number to replace with your token:\n")
playeronechoice = input("Type a number to replace with your token on the board:\n")
indexOne = gBoard.index(playeronechoice)
print ("##DEBUG:", indexOne)
gBoard[indexOne] = (playeronechoice, "##")
for row in gBoard: ##Shows the updated board
    print(row)
```

Instead it errors out like so:

```
Type a number to replace with your token on the board:
60
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\####.py", line 101, in <module>
    indexOne = gBoard.index(playeronechoice)
ValueError: '60' is not in list
```

Line 101: indexOne = gBoard.index(playeronechoice)

Comment: `gBoard` is a list of lists.  All of its top-level elements are lists, not strings.  You need to search the sub-lists for the string.

Comment: [This deep indexing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15233895/10753968) should help

Comment: How would I do that if I didn't know what list the users input will be in?

Comment: @E.V.A. You search them all.  For each sub-list, see if the string is present.

Comment: @E.V.A. you search through each list, or create a mapping of index to values to check if a number exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
playerOneChoice = str(input("Type a number to replace with your token on the board:\n"))

for row in range(len(gBoard)):
    for col in range(len(gBoard[row])):
        if playerOneChoice == gBoard[int(row)][int(col)]:
            gBoard[int(row)][int(col)] = "$$"  # or concatenate with existing value
for row in gBoard:
    print(row)
```

**Output**

```
Type a number to replace with your token on the board: 26
['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08']
['09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16']
['17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24']
['25', '$$', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32']
['33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40']
['41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48']
['49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56']
['57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64']
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can directly calculate the index with Python's `divmod` (but first subtracting 1):

```
playeronechoice = int(input("Type a number to replace with your token on the board:\n"))

if not 1 <= playeronechoice <= 64:
    print("no such position exists")
else:
    row, col = divmod(playeronechoice - 1, 8)
    gBoard[row][col] = "@"                     # putting "@" as an example
```

When user gives `60`, `divmod(59, 8)` gives `7, 3`. In fact, if we look at 7th row 3th column `60` is there. We subtract 1 in divmod because Python is 0-indexed.